# Android Universal image loader and several image's urls

Tags: android, image, url

I'm using an universal image loader to load images from specified url into imageview. But if there are several possible urls of one image e.g. image may be stored in `www.example.com/image.png` or `www.example.com/image.jpg` or `www.example.com/image.gif` and I need to display first existing image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try each one until it works?

Comment: Do You mean imageLoader.displayImage(url1, imageView); imageLoader.displayImage(url2, imageView); etc?

Answer (score 1):

If url are available in xml then you have to read those url using DOMParser or any other xml parser. Once you got the required url, feed it to the Universal Image Loader

```
ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageView image;

private void loadImageFromURL(String url) {
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .showImageForEmptyUrl(R.drawable.app_icon).cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc().build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                new ImageLoadingListener() {
            public void onLoadingComplete() {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            public void onLoadingFailed() {

                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            public void onLoadingStarted() {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
```